# How to add psuedo element :after using REACT

Tags: reactjs, pseudo-element

I am trying to get the envelope icon to show after the Envelope link using REACT

in my index.js file, I have:

```
              <Envelopestyling>
               
                <p><i className="fas fa-envelope"><Link>Envelope</Link></i></p>
              </Envelopestyling>
```

in my styling.js file, I have:

```
export const Envelopestyling = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;

& . fas fa-envelope{ position: absolute, top:10px, colour: #000}
& .fas fa-envelope:after{
content:"\f0e0";
}
`;
```

All this does is duplicate the envelope icon: one in before the Envelope link and another after it but what I want is the envelope after the Envelope Link.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you show detail file `styling.js` and how you use this file in `index.js`?

Comment: @Viet  Added..Thank you

Comment: Can you please complete code or codescandbox.io/fiddle to see why your code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem is you are using css selector wrong way. You need to update like this:

```
& .fas.fa-envelope{ position: absolute, top:10px, colour: #000}
& .fas.fa-envelope:after{
  content:"\f0e0";
}
```

Comment: didn't work still getting the same result @Viet